# Error in video streaming (Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401)

Tags: java

I am trying to stream video from IP camera. and it is showing the error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 401 for URL:
>   http://192.168.43.1:8080/snapshot.cgi?user=admin&pwd=123456"

### My Following code is:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
public class TestconnectionCamera {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CanvasFrame CamWindow = new CanvasFrame("Camera");

    String Cam1Jpeg_url = "http://192.168.43.1:8080/snapshot.cgi?user=admin&pwd=123456";
    URL url = new URL(Cam1Jpeg_url);

    while(true){
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
    CamWindow.showImage(image);
    is.close();
    }
}
}
```

---

::: I'll be glad if anyone help me to solve the problem.:::

Comment: 401 means that you're unauthorized. Try passing the username/password in an Authorization header.

Comment: https://httpstatuses.com/401